# cannot access zzbck class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project which has many libraries included gms:play-services it was working fine but when I add this

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.4.0" implementation 'com.rahnema.vas3gapi:vas3g-api:2.0.0'
```

i am getting

```
Error:(23, 36) error: cannot access zzbck class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found
```

in my MessageReciverSerivce and here is my app.build.gralde file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arizeh.arizeh"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 31
        versionName "3.0.5"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.2@aar'

    compile 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.4.0"
    implementation 'com.rahnema.vas3gapi:vas3g-api:2.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```